# log4j2 log file is not generating

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j2

the log file is generated when I run the code within IDE (Intellij IDEA).

as soon as I create runnable jar of the code and then try to run the jar then the logs are not generating.

I have made sure the log4j2.xml file is a part of classpath.

is there anything extra I have to do while creating jar in the Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the FAQ: [How do I debug my configuration?](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting)

*First, make sure you have the right jar files on your classpath. You need at least log4j-api and log4j-core.
Next, check the name of your configuration file. By default, log4j2 will look for a configuration file named log4j2.xml on the classpath. Note the “2” in the file name! (See the [configuration manual page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) for more details.)*

**From log4j-2.9 onward**

*From log4j-2.9 onward, log4j2 will print all internal logging to the console if system property log4j2.debug is either defined empty or its value equals to true (ignoring case).*

**Prior to log4j-2.9**

*Prior to log4j-2.9, there are two places where internal logging can be controlled:*

*If the configuration file is found correctly, log4j2 internal status logging can be controlled by setting  in the configuration file. This will display detailed log4j2-internal log statements on the console about what happens during the configuration process. This may be useful to trouble-shoot configuration issues. By default the status logger level is WARN, so you only see notifications when there is a problem.*

*If the configuration file is not found correctly, you can still enable log4j2 internal status logging by setting system property -Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE.*